# Clarification on paragraph in Pugh's Real Mathematical Analysis about not all norms come from inner products

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, normed-spaces, inner-products

Pugh states the following in Chapter 1 of his book, *Real Mathematical Analysis*:

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

Unfortunately, I'm having a hard time making sense of how he uses this unit sphere he brings up. I assume the norm was just something he thought of that satisfied the necessary properties of a norm but I don't understand how the unit sphere comes into play. How is the perimeter known? And, how do we know the set defined as $\{v\in V:\langle v,v \rangle =1\}$ looks like the unit sphere when the inner product isn't explicitly defined, is this somehow known from the properties of inner products (bilinearity, symmetry, and positive definiteness) alone?

Moreover, whats the relationship between corners/smoothness and whether or not it arose from an inner product?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can show is that the unit ball of any finite dimensional inner product space is an ellipsoid.  That is, there exists a linear, invertible transformation $R$ such that the image of the unit ball is a sphere.

To see this, note that any inner product on $\mathbb R^n$ is of the form $\langle x,y\rangle = x^T A y$ for some positive definite matrix $A$.  So apply the Cholesky factorization $A = R^T R$ to see that $\langle x,y\rangle = (Rx)^T (Ry)$.  Then the image under $R$ of the unit ball induced by $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is a sphere.

Another way to understand that not all norms come from an inner product is that any norm that comes from an inner product satisfies the polarization identity, that is
$$ \|x\|^2 + \|y\|^2 = \tfrac12(\|x+y\|^2 + \|x-y\|^2) ,$$
and it can be shown that this is an if and only if condition.  So just show that the max norm, or the taxi-cab norm fails this condition.